# What is the German original of "Head off, tail off - bunny"?

Tags: proverb

Recently, a popular post at [*Seasoned Advice*](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) discussed the difference between (decapitated and skinned) rabbits and cats, following the OP's suspicion of a fraud in a shipment of rabbit meat.

@Stephie posted [an answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/56421) that mentioned an old German saying that roughly translates to English as "**head off, tail off - bunny**".

What is the German original?

If available, I would also like to know more about the origin and usage of this saying.

Comment: I've never heard about the saying, but apparently there is a song named ["Kopf ab, Schwanz ab, Has!"](http://www.songtexte.com/songtext/wizo/kopf-ab-schwanz-ab-has-2bdcc89a.html) by the German punk band WIZO. Its lyrics made me giggle.^^

Comment: Apparently, it is _Kopf ab, Schwanz ab – Has_, [a song by WIZO](http://youtu.be/N0d-Lm4BIQE). I only learned about it by searching for the retranslation; if it really is an old saying, it isn't known everywhere, at least. (Edit: It appears I am a bit slow. :) Leaving the comment as further evidence for it being not too well-known.)

Comment: For some reason I keep thinking about the Blackadder quote ‘I have a plan so cunning you could stick a tail on it and call it a weasel!’ Only mildly related, though.

Comment: Could be regional, known in Swabia, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For lack of better sources, I claim anecdotal evidence: My mother heard

> "Kopf weg Schwanz weg: Has!"

when she was a child in the 1950s. It appears to be way older than this (I suppose I could check with some elder relatives, if necessary.).

The origin is undoubtedly the fact that all meat was a rare food and valuable source of protein in rural/poorer groups and times of famine or at least malnutrition were common in Europe for centuries. The superficial similarities between a roast cat and a roast rabbit<sup>1</sup> together with a wider definition of meat fit for human consumption ([beaver](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biber#Kulturaspekte) anyone?) brought cats on the table, too.

And of course there is the term "[Dachhase](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dachhase)" for cat - according to Wikipedia dating back to the siege of Vienna 1683 - also indicating culinary uses of domesticated cats.

In newer sources this is often refered to as a joke:

- There is a Swabian humorous story of the poor family who served the neighbour's cat at a wedding, complete with a boy spilling the beans afterwards with said quote. (Link [here](http://www.stuttgarter-nachrichten.de/inhalt.auf-gut-schwaebisch-du-hosch-halt-da-vadder-gnomma.dea883b8-c0f3-4e18-b84a-ceda954564e8.html) in Swabian dialect, see last paragraph.)
- The Movie "[Der Etappenhase](http://www.moviepilot.de/movies/der-etappenhase)" (1937) has this substiution as main motiv.

---

<sup>1</sup> note: both rabbit *and* hare was and is often called "Hase", the terms "Feldhase" = hare and "Stallhase" = domesticated rabbit are still used although not zoologigally correct.

Answer (score -1):

**Kopf ab, Schwanz ab: Has' ist's!**

Comment: Welcome to German.SE.  Do you have any more to say than just the possible original translation? Like where it comes from. Maybe a source. And maybe formatted as normal text - or in case you add context than as quoted text? (need help on that?)